# Has it been proven that the Cheeger constant is attainable on surface?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

Recently, I have been studying the monotonicity of the [Cheeger constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheeger_constant) under Ricci flow on surfaces. In fact, I want to use the monotonicity  to prove the convergence of Ricci flow on $S^2$, which was first proven by [Bennett Chow](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Bennett-Chow/publication/247980499_The_Ricci_flow_on_the_2-sphere/links/0f317538155703da2a000000/The-Ricci-flow-on-the-2-sphere.pdf). Then, [Hamilton](https://sci-hub.ru/10.1515/9781400882571-013) proved it once more.

When I dealt with it, I found a way to prove the attainability of the Cheeger constant. Although I haven't done the exact calculations yet, I think the proof for  compact Riemannian surfaces is at least correct.

So I searched on Google for information on the attainability of the Cheeger constant, but I couldn't find anything. Therefore, I want to know if this problem has been studied.

I am a beginner in Geometrical Analysis and I do not have an adviser to guide me. This platform is my only option to seek assistance. I appreciate any help provided.

Comment: You can prove this using the direct method in the class of sets of finite perimeter; the regularity theory needed to then show it's smooth is pretty classical. This approach has existed at least since De Giorgi ('60s), though I don't know of the first reference for this specific problem. In 2D in particular, it could probably be done more easily for the same reason it's easier to find minimizing geodesics, so there may be even earlier proofs.

Comment: If you are interested in the direct method approach, I would recommend F. Maggi's book on geometric measure theory (it will be in Euclidean space, but the ideas translate directly). In general you might have more luck searching for "relative isoperimetric inequality" and similar.

Comment: @user378654  Why is everything I think of proven : (   But the  Maggi's book is very good. Thanks.